# Why can't I set a series type to equal another series type with Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm fairly new to python so forgive me if this seems like a simple question.

I have a dataframe. My goal is to take the values of a dataframe and convert it into another type and replace that column. Here is the codes:

```
strtotime = {}
for x in range(0,len(results['CreationDate'])):
    strtotime[x] = datetime.strptime(results['CreationDate'][x], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
results['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(strtotime))
```

I stored the values as a dictionary, converted it to a series using `pd.Series`, at which point I'm fairly certain I can just replace one series with another:

i.e `results['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(strtotime))`

but what I get in return for results is a column of `NaT` instead of these neat datetimes `2015-01-01 10:59:37.403`.

I then used `results['CreationDate'] = list(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(strtotime)))`

which worked perfectly as I wanted it to be. So my question is why is this the case? Does it even have anything to do with object types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a Series to a DataFrame column, pandas matches the new values according to the *index*.  Your original DataFrame presumably has some meaningful index, but your new Series it just has the default index of 0, 1, 2, 3...  because those are the keys in your dictionary.  Here is a simple example:

```
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]}, index=[10, 11, 12])
>>> d
    A  B
10  1  4
11  2  5
12  3  6
>>> d["C"] = pandas.Series([8, 88, 888])
>>> d
    A  B   C
10  1  4 NaN
11  2  5 NaN
12  3  6 NaN
>>> d["C"] = pandas.Series([8, 88, 888], index=[10, 11, 12])
>>> d
    A  B    C
10  1  4    8
11  2  5   88
12  3  6  888
```

Notice that assigning a series with the wrong index resulted in NaN, but creating the new Series with the same index results in the values being put in as expected.

In your case, you are creating your new Series by applying a function to each element of the original column.  Don't iterate to do that.  Use the `.map` method.  In this case, there is a builtin pandas function to convert a string to a datetime:

```
results['CreationDate'] = results['CreationDate'].map(pandas.to_datetime)
```

`.map` gives a new Series with the same index as the old.  (If your dates don't parse correctly, you can apply a `lambda` that supplies a `format` argument to `to_datetime`.)

(As piRsquared noted in a comment, `to_datetime` actually accepts a Series argument, so you can just do `results['CreationDate'] = pandas.to_datetime(results['CreationDate'])`.)

Comment: `pd.Series(strtotime)` was created from a dictionary.  Meaning, the index was specified.  Therefore, default wasn't used.  However, your point is still valid.  And... great answer deserving of up-votes considering the depth of explanation.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use `map` when `pd.to_datetime` accepts a `pd.Series`.  This should work `pandas.to_datetime(results['CreationDate'])`

Comment: @piRSquared: Ah, I forgot that you can pass the Series directly like that, yeah, that is better.